# Include special characters in AD Request output to xml

Tags: c#, xml, active-directory, ldap, linq-to-xml

We need to provide a mechanism for importing Active Directory Users into MSSQL2012  This process will take two stages, being the export to xml from AD and the import to SQL from xml.

I think i have a few problems with formatting for special characters.
 for example we have some domains with dn's including "\" and also "&".

When I generate an xml file and view it in notepad, these two characters are shown as `\\` and `&amp;` .

Is this correct for xml? and if so how do i get the OPENXML at the other end to recognise these characters correctly for inserting into SQL?

**Update**

So I have established that `&amp;` is being correctly converted to & in my OPENXML query. however i think i need to get the initial output of `\\` to be output to xml as \ My question is are there any other characters which are escaped in such a way in the cn?

Comment: How are you exporting to XML? Backslashes are fine in XML, but `&` needs to be escaped as `&amp;`. An XML API should do this for you automatically.

Comment: sorry please have updated (had to excase the output in my post in codeblocks as it was modifyng them on post :)). So my question is is this correct output for xml? then? and how do i convert it at the other end?

Comment: No, `\` should just be `\\`. It would help if you'd show the code you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jon Skeet
 Thanks for your help.

I found that since \ is stored in ldap or is returned as `\\` i had to do a

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(mystring_containing_escaped_backslash);
```

Prior to saving the value in my xml file. Which then mean't my xml was all escaped consistantly. So when i read it back in in the importer it correctly unescaped escaped items.